# Downloading a file generated by shiny

Tags: r, mongodb, shiny, mongolite

I'm trying to download a BSON file that I export to my shiny app from a MongoDB using the mongolite package. This is the code in my download button:

```
output$downloadTiming <- downloadHandler(
  filename = "/keyTiming.bson",
  content = function(fileToDownload){

    mongolite::mongo(
      collection = "keyTiming",
      url = "mongodb://<User>:<Pass>@<url>"
    )$export(fileToDownload, bson = TRUE)
  }
)
```

When I try to download it, it says "Error: inherits(con, "connection") is not TRUE". I have spent a good amount of time researching and have found nothing, and hope that someone here can be of use.

Comment: Can you confirm what you're trying to do: Are you using Shiny to extract data from MongoDB and then export it to disk/hard drive, OR are you using shiny to read data from MongoDB so it's available within the shiny app?

Comment: Export to disk/hard drive using a download button

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually. The final code looks like this

```
   output$downloadTiming <- downloadHandler(
  filename <- function(){
    return("timingOut.bson")
  },
  content <- function(file){

    outFile = file("timingOut.bson")

    mongolite::mongo(
      collection = "timings",
      url = "mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<database>"
    )$export(outFile, bson = TRUE)

    file.copy("timingOut.bson", file, overwrite = TRUE)
  }
)
```